# Animate UIView with origin point is not working perfectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode7, ios-animations

I want to animate a view to a specified origin when ever someone touched it and then comeback to its original position whenever user touched it again. I am using AutoLayout in my storyboard to align my views.
It first go upward with perfect position but does not come back to its original position perfectly.
I store the staring origin value in a CGFloat variable in my viewDidLoad method and then re assign that object to bring back the view.
Here is my code 
Animation for upward (This is working perfect)

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
CGRect frame = _pickLocationView.frame;
frame.origin.y = _cityLabelView.frame.origin.y;
_pickLocationView.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Animation for Downward. (This method has some issue)

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
CGRect frame = _pickLocationView.frame;
frame.origin.y = kDefaultOriginOfPickLocationView;
_pickLocationView.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: How do you call the Animation for Downward ??

Comment: by assigning the default origin of that view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion:
Use the method - `[self setNeedsLayout]` before the animation starts.

Comment: Should i just invoke the [self setNeedsLayout] method or override and then invoke?
Sorry if it is a stupid question but i am new with iOS programming.

Comment: Use it before [UIView commitAnimation]. just write the above piece code in my answer. see if any changes takes place. if not then try using the method after commitAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

The frame is not guaranteed to have its final dimensions and position in `viewDidLoad`. Use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to set your original values instead. Note that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be called multiple times if the bounds of your view changes.

In your case you could also just save the original value just before you start the first animation.